# Getting full text out of acronyms in TweetNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, tweets

[TweetNLP](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/) provides tokenizer and part-of-speech tagger for tweets, which is really cool. Now, I wonder if I can take it a step further and extract acronyms. For example, when I get a tweet "ikr", I would be able to look it up and get "I know, right?". I guess I can write my own dictionary, but it seems that there should already be one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I end up doing is to use StanfordNLP with GATE tweeter model.

Sample tweet:

> ikr smh he asked fir yo last name so he can add u on fb lololol

Results without gate-EN-twitter.model

```
word: ikr :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: smh :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: asked :: pos: VBD :: ne:O
word: fir :: pos: NNP :: ne:O
word: yo :: pos: NNP :: ne:O
word: last :: pos: JJ :: ne:O
word: name :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: so :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: can :: pos: MD :: ne:O
word: add :: pos: VB :: ne:O
word: u :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: on :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: fb :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: lololol :: pos: NN :: ne:O
```

Results with gate-EN-twitter.model

```
word: ikr :: pos: UH :: ne:O
word: smh :: pos: UH :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: asked :: pos: VBD :: ne:O
word: fir :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: yo :: pos: PRP$ :: ne:O
word: last :: pos: JJ :: ne:O
word: name :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: so :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: can :: pos: MD :: ne:O
word: add :: pos: VB :: ne:O
word: u :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: on :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: fb :: pos: NNP :: ne:O
word: lololol :: pos: UH :: ne:O
```

Now, I am able to identify slang by looking at the tag of UH and go against my custom dictionary.

Still puzzled why it was not already available out there, but it solves my issue at the moment.

Comment: See below for complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Download StanfordNLP from their website or use it as maven dependency. I used 3.1.1 version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Download [Gate tweeter model](http://downloads.gate.ac.uk/twitie/gate-EN-twitter.model).

Add it to your properties file

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
props.put("pos.model", "gate-EN-twitter.model");
props.put("dcoref.score", true);
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

and run POS

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such corpus; but you can scrape the information you need from these websites: 
http://www.allacronyms.com/twitter/topic
http://www.abbreviations.com/acronyms/TWITTER

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's my back up plan. I would have a dictionary of such terms, and if TweetNLP shows with big confidence that it just parsed an interjection, I would access my dictionary to look up: LOL and then substitute it to laughing out loud. If not, found, I would log it, and then manually try to decipher what it was and add it to the dictionary. Maybe I can do it for Apache OpenNLP and contribute as a plugin if this functionality is not available at this time...